# why is django not picking up my base.html in my global templates folder

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a `base.html` file in my project *templates* folder.

The problem is that the code `{%extends 'base.html'%}` in my `index.html` creates errors when I try to inherit from the `base.html` file.

My project name is *my_blog*. The app name is *blog*. The settings in the installed app includes the `blog app ['blog']`. And I also have my `BASE_DIR/templates` settings set.

I tried changing the view called home page:

```
def homepage(request):
   return render(request,"blog/index.html")
```

to

```
def homepage(request):
   return render(request,"templates/blog/index.html")
```

I even tried

```
def homepage(request):
   return render(request,"index.html")
```

here is some more information if it helps:

TemplateDoesNotExist at /
base.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 4.2
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:
base.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\27388808\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py, line 84, in reraise
Raised during:  blog.views.start_page
Python Executable:  C:\Users\27388808\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.2
Python Path:
['C:\Users\27388808\chantellblog',
'C:\Users\27388808\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python311.zip',
'C:\Users\27388808\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\DLLs',
'C:\Users\27388808\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib',
'C:\Users\27388808\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311',
'C:\Users\27388808\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib

Comment: Not enough information and not in correct format as well. At least provide a proper formatting that all can understand. But "assuming" from your question above you are trying to inherit from ```base.html``` and you are extending your ```index.html``` that doesn't makes sense  try ```{% extends 'base.html' %}```

Comment: Your question can basically be summarized as _"I am getting an error, how can I fix it?"_. We can't help as we don't even know what the error message is.

Comment: If you write a view that uses "base.html" as a template, does that work?

Comment: Without more detail it gone a be complecated to answer... Not because it's hard but because we doesn't have enought information to answer. Please share your settings key. Your directories architecture then your trace.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

things that comes to my mind is:

1- you could misspelled templates folder in your base directory

2- your templates folder path is incorrect, the folder must be next to 'manage.py' file

3- in your 'blog' folder you must have another 'templates' folder and inside that you must have a 'blog' folder and inside that one you should create your 'index.html' file

4- on view.py file:

```
def homepage(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request,"blog/index.html", context)
```

and finally you should check you urls.py files, check if you include the urls.py from your 'blog' app correctly

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

these are the things that I think you should check based on the limited information that you gave

I hope this helps you